# Powershell - how do you use a variable to define a new array line with a number of elements dynamically determined

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell

```
 $array = @()
$line = "`$var1,`$var2"

for ($n = 0; $n -eq 5 , $n++ ){ $line= "$line"+",0"}

$array += ,@($line)
$array += ,@($line)
```

The challenge is i want it to create the array line with a dynamic number of columns equal to 2 + $n with the $n columns having a value of 0.

instead i get a single element as $var1,$var2,0,0,0,0,0

How can i escape it and get my line created with the $n+2 columns?

Expected Output:

```
$array[0][0] will return contents of $var1
$array[0][1] will return contents of $var2
$array[0][2] will return 0
$array[0][3] will return 0
$array[0][4] will return 0

$array[1][0] will return contents of $var1
$array[1][1] will return contents of $var2
$array[1][2] will return 0
$array[1][3] will return 0
$array[1][4] will return 0
```

etc

So i can update an element in a line with

```
$array[0][4] = 1
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you are looking for, just type out a few lines...

Comment: Expecting an array which i can return

$array[0][0] will return contents of $var1
$array[0][1] will return contents of $var2
$array[0][2] will return 0
$array[0][3] will return 0
$array[0][4] will return 0

etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understant your question, here is the way to create a two dimension array in PowerShell :

```
$tab= new-object ‘object[,]’ 3,3
$tab[0,0] = "hello"
```

The one your are usin is an array of array :

```
$tab = ("hello","coucou"),("blue","red")
$tab[0][1]
```

In your script $line = `"$var1,$var2"` do not create an array you should write `$line = "$var1","$var2"`.

Your `for` loop has a typo `;` should replace `,` and you should begin at the actual length of the original tab `$line`.

Here is your code after correction :

```
$array = @()
$line = "`$var1","`$var2"
for ($n = $line.Length; $n -le 5 ; $n++ ){ $line+= "0"}
$array += ,@($line)
```

Then

```
$array[0][1]
$var2
```

Comment: Cheers JPBLanc, That looks like it will do the trick, gotta keep thinking of powershells multidimensional arrays as being arrays in arrays.

Comment: @Onthax, You can perhaps put it as answered. I add a remark concerning arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
  $array = @(@(),@());
    $var1="test"
    $var2="test1"

    [string] $line = "$var1,$var2"

    for ($n = 0; $n -le 5 ; $n++ )
    { 

    $line+=",0"
    }

    $line
    $array[0]+=$line.Split(",")
    $array
```

Output:
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $array[0][0]
test

[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $array[0][1]
test1
0

0

0

0

Comment: Need to keep it as a multi-dimensional as i will have a few hundred lines or 7-31+ columns (column length determined via user input)

Comment: @Onthax, how about now?